# Jump and colisions in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, collision

I'm trying to create a platformer on iphone, and cocos2d.
I haven't resolved to using Box2D yet ... but depending on how I can solve this, or not, I may have to use it.

My problem is jumping.
When my character (sprite) runs along a flat ledge, and I try to jump at the end of the ledge, sometimes, effectively, I'm pressing the jump right after the character has effectivelly "walked" off the ledge.
Visually and physically it feels very bizarre, because I'm almost sure each time I'm pressing at the last moment, but no, it's one loop too late.

Has anyone encountered the same kind of problem, and know of a smart way of dealing with it ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, in your case you can simple take into account some precision that will allow you oto make your jump a bit after "leaving" platform.

Anyway, box2d is a rather good physical engine that allows you to detect collisions and simulate bodies behavior(for example, it can automatically apply rotation to objects after collision). And there is a lot of manuals in the internet, that will help you to understand how it works.

Comment: Not sure what you meen with "precision". Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using only the character's position to determine if he's still on the ledge. If so, the character will "lose his footing" the moment his center point passes over the ledge. No platformer does that.

Instead, you should test the entire bounding box width of the character. As long as either the lower left or the lower right corner of the bounding box is still on a walkable plane, the character can't fall off the ledge. You'll see this in many platformers where characters still stand on a ledge with just one foot still on the ledge.

**Two things you might be interested in:**

This [Guide to implementing 2D Platformers](http://higherorderfun.com/blog/2012/05/20/the-guide-to-implementing-2d-platformers/). Covers almost everything you need to know. No code but easy to follow instructions for the algorithms.

Then there's [Commander Cool](http://www.payloadz.com/go/jump?id=1648092&aff_id=3419318), a commercial platformer game kit with cocos2d & box2d. If you're interested in speeding up development rather than spending time re-inventing the wheel aka the platformer framework code.

Comment: I'm using the bounding box system and slimmed it in order to fit the "slim" character in the 48x48px sprite.

Algo is:
- position updates every 1/60 of a second
- collision tests are made (bounding box wise)
- Async jumps can come from touches

I think my problem lies in: i calculate (update) the destination to somewhere "off" the ledge (movement + gravity) then I go through the collisions.
Jump is probably pressed after the dest is calculated, and since destination is "off" the ledge or in the air ... it voids the jump.

Any thoughts ?

I'll look into the 2 links you gave. Looks interesting.